# Header of html page adjusting a div to float left if chars are more for a field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a situation here as follows:

```
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My Header</title>


        <style>
            /* Global */
            * {
                margin: 0;
            }
            html, body {
                height: 99%;
                margin-top:5px;margin-left:5px;
                margin-right:5px;
            }
            /* Header Menu*/
            .task-bar{
                width:80px;
                background-color:#fff;
                border:1px solid green;
                position: absolute;
            }

            .task-bar span{
                color:#000;
                display:block;
                font-size:8pt;
                cursor:pointer;
                text-decoration:none;
            }

            .task-bar span:hover{
                color:red;
            }

            /* Header */
            .container{
                min-height: 100%;
                height: auto !important;
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0 auto -3em;
                width:100%;
                font-family:Segoe UI;
                color:#fff;
            }
        </style>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){ 
                 $('.task-icon').click(function(){
                        $(".task-bar").slideToggle();
                 });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <!-- Header Div -->
    <div class="container">
        <table width="100%" style="background-color:#333030;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div style="padding-top:15px;padding-left:20px;font-size:36px;">Header Header Header Header</div>
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding-top:10px;">
                        <div style="padding-left:10px;color:#FFFFFF;" id="userRole">
                            UserName<br/>
                            <i>Role Role Role</i>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="task-icon"><img src="profile.png"/></div>
                        <div class="task-bar" style="display:none;">
                            <span id="">&nbsp;Change Role</span>
                            <span id="">&nbsp;Profile</span>
                            <span id="">&nbsp;Preferences</span>
                            <span id="logout">&nbsp;Sign Out</span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have to dynamically display the Username and role and it can be less characters and more too... so it is not adjusting the correct way i want... it should be close to profile.png but when the role/username is 20-25 characters den it gets far away or distorted. I want something to stick to profile.png and if it is more chars den it should float: left and stick to profile.png.

```
Usernameeeeeeeeeeee - Profile.png
Role                -   


OR

username                - Profile.png
Roleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee -
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

because tables that's why.

But in all seriousness if it's an issue merge the two into one td.

Comment: But how.. if i keep dem in one td den it will be under not parallel to the image file. Suggest?